# How to change the child element in SOAPBODY

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

I have a soapMessage which i am writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream to log the request
But I have to change p803:Credential child element value before i log it, how can I do this?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMessageCtx.getMessage().writeTo(out);
```

Here is the  request xml

```
<soapenv:Body>
<p803:multiple xmlns:p803="http://www.abc.com/model">

<p803:RequestContext>
<p803:Credential>2222222/iuuiiiuuuu</p803:Credential>
```

Comment: Do you want to change it in your SoapHandler?

Comment: Maybe you can provide some context? Manipulation of a message before logging it does not seem to make sense (at least for me).

Comment: I need to chnage the value of <p803:Credential>

Comment: @ bitil
I need to change the value of <p803:Credential> in the soap body not in the header with any of existing methods
@home
I dont want to log the request with credentials, the origibal request before we manipulate would remain un chanaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SOAPMessage soapMsg = soapMessageCtx.getMessage();
NodeList credentials = soapMsg
                        .getSOAPBody()
                        .getElementsByTagNameNS("http://rsi.chase.com/model", "Credential");

int len = credentials.length();
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
    credentials.item(i).setTextContent("new credential content goes here...");
}

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMsg.writeTo(out);

// ...
```

Comment: can't we do this with any of the existing SOAPEnvelope methods?

Comment: @SatishUppalapati What is the class of `soapMessageCtx` ?

Comment: import javax.xml.rpc.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext

Comment: Thanks alot,this is exactly what am looking for